# Again about Spinner in SDK12

Tags: android, spinner, popupwindow

I have created a `spinner.xml` in my project, and what I want to do is to add this spinner to a `popupwindow` ,But something seems "wrong". But I have checked my code several times and noting wrong with it.
My code is here:

```
public void showCustomSpinner(Context context, View parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vPopupView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, null, false);

mySpinner2 = (Spinner) vPopupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String> this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countriesStr2);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
mySpinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

mCustomSpinner = new PopupWindow(vPopupView, 200, 400,true);
mCustomSpinner.showAsDropDown(parent);
```

My problem is : Every time I run this code, it crashes.But I cannot find the mistake,cause this piece of code is the same as the one in another project which runs in SDK10 and goes well. So is it the problem of the SDK12?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share some of the code that doesn't work, or any errors you are getting?

Comment: I'm sorry!But I was afraid of the number of the comment's characters limit~.~  Here is my code:  'code' public void showCustomSpinner(Context context, View parent) {LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);vPopupView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, null, false);mySpinner2 = (Spinner) vPopupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countriesStr2);
'code'

Comment: adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
mySpinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);mCustomSpinner = new PopupWindow(vPopupView, 200, 400,true);mCustomSpinner.showAsDropDown(parent);}

Comment: Please do not add large code parts as comments. Instead edit your original question to add it. Also, you still didn't mention what problems exactly you are having with this code.

Comment: @THelper: I feel so sorry about that! And I'll improve my expression !

Comment: I have what seems to be the same problem, since I upgraded my target API to 14.  Originally I was targeting Android 2.1 and the spinners worked perfectly within the popup window I use.  Now that I've changed versions (to handle the new AdMob SDK), my spinners crash as above.

Comment: Converting my popup code to Dialog code made the crashes go away.  I'm not sure yet why spinners within a popup caused a crash, but they do not in a dialog.